# LINQ: select first value of every minute in table

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of object like this one:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Snapshot            | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:00:04 |
| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:01:15 |
| 3           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:01:23 |
| 4           | 3          | 2019-03-07 20:01:45 |
| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:02:10 |
| 6           | 7          | 2019-03-07 20:02:45 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:03:10 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:04:30 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

How to select only records from every minute or hour...

The result should be something like this:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Snapshot            | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:00:04 |
| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:01:15 |  
| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:02:10 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:03:10 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:04:30 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

It the moment I'm fetching those kind of records using thisq SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM log 
WHERE Snapshot IN ( SELECT MIN(Snapshot) AS snaptime FROM log GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(snaptime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))
```

but I need somehow to convert this query to LINQ if it is possible.

Comment: DataType of the `Snapshot` column?

Comment: Sorry... It's DateTime

Comment: Is the data in memory? Or in a database? i.e. is this EF or LINQ to Objects?

Comment: The data is in memory. They are stored in List. It is LINQ to objects.

Comment: I think you are confused somehow. sql gives you executable query which connects to your db. Linq is a selector/filter thing on other hand. we have to assign db object to Linq to get some selection on it. but on sql its a query. Got it?

Comment: @Josef Check this:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f33638/1

Comment: So you can't replace the sql to Linq. what you can do is type conversion of sql object to Linq. so you need to execute the sql and assign object to Linq and here you go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you wanna group by minute and display only the first record of each minute:

```
var query = list
    .OrderBy(x => x.Snapshot)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Snapshot.Date.AddMinutes((int)x.Snapshot.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes))
    .Select(minuteGroup => minuteGroup.First());
```

Comment: How would you modify if you wanted to group by every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will only give results where there is a measurement for each minute.  If you have minutes 1,2,5,6 there will be no data for minutes 3 & 4.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Snapshot", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:00:04")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:01:15")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:01:23")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 3, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:01:45")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 5, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:02:10")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, 7, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:02:45")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, 1, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:03:10")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 0, DateTime.Parse("2019-03-07 20:04:30") });

            List<DataRow> results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot"))
                .GroupBy(x => new DateTime(
                    x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot").Year,
                    x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot").Month,
                    x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot").Day,
                    x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot").Hour,
                    x.Field<DateTime>("Snapshot").Minute,
                    0
                    ))
                .Select(x => x.First())
                .ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd wanted the first item per day, you'd grouped your data into groups of snapshots made on the same day, sort them, and then take the first one.

I'll use [the overload of Enumerable.GroupBy that has a ResultSelector as parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__),
so I don't have to use a Select after the Groupby.

```
var firstPerDay = mySnapShots.GroupBy(       // make groups with same date       
    // parameter keySelector: make groups of SnapShots with the same date:
    snapShot => snapShot.DateTime.Date,

    // parameter ResultSelector: use the date, and all snapShots made on this date
    // to select one new object:
    (date, snapshotsOnThisDate) => 

         // the selected object is the first one if you sort them in ascending order
         snapShotsOnThisDate.OrderBy(snapShot => snapShot.DateTime)
                            .FirstOrDefault());
```

If desired you could separate the GroupBy and the Select:

```
var firstPerDay = mySnapShots.GroupBy(snapShot => snapShot.DateTime.Date)
    .Select(snapShotPerDayGroup => snapShotPerDayGroup
        .OrderBy(snapShot => snapShot.DateTime)
        .FirstOrDefault());
```

The only difference with your problem is that you don't want to make groups of SnapShots made on the same Date, but in the same Minute.

A neat method would be to create an extension function of the DateTime struct, that extracts the Date + Hour + Minute, similar to the DateTime.Date function. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx#targetText=Extension%20methods%20are%20a%20very,was%20a%20first%2Dclass%20method.). Note: this will only work with an IEnumerable, not with an IQueryable (or: AsEnumerable, not AsQueryable).

Let's first see the [source code of DateTime.Date](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,03ba40168be1388d):

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get
    {
        Int64 ticks = InternalTicks;
        return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks - ticks % TicksPerDay) | InternalKind);
    }
}
```

Your code will be very similar. Instead of TicksPerDay, you'll use TicksPerSecond. Alas you can't use DateTime.TicksPerMinute, because it's declared private. Luckily you can use TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute instead.

```
public static DateTime DateHourMinute(this DateTime date)
{
    Int64 ticks = Ticks;
    return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks - ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) | InternalKind);
}
```

So your query will be:

```
    var firstPerDay = mySnapShots.GroupBy(       // make groups with same date       
    // parameter keySelector: make groups of SnapShots with the same date:
    snapShot => snapShot.DateTime.DateHourMinute,

    // etc.
```